# Django passing values ​from views to html

Tags: python, html, django, web, backend

I have two pages for reserving a table in a restaurant, and their logic is as follows: on the first page, the user enters their contact details, reservation date, and number of guests, and then clicks the "Next" button. They are then redirected to the second page, where they need to select a table and time (the available time slots are generated based on the selected date). The problem is that I can't pass the time values to the template of the second page through the view. Here's a rough example of the code:

```
def contact_details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form data from the request
        # ...

        # Store the form data in the session
        request.session['client_name'] = client_name
        request.session['client_email'] = client_email
        request.session['client_phone'] = client_phone
        request.session['number_of_guests'] = number_of_guests
        request.session['reservation_date'] = reservation_date
        request.session['reservation_time'] = [str(time) for time in free_time()]

        return redirect('reservation_data')

    return render(request, 'contact_details.html')

def reservation_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form data from the session
        # ...

        # Create the reservation using the form data
        # ...

        # Clear the session data
        request.session.clear()

        return redirect('reservation_detail', pk=reservation.pk)

    return render(request, 'reservation_data.html')
```

I understand that values are typically passed to the template using render, but if I use render in the first view, the second view won't be triggered to save the form values. So, I'm using redirect. Combining the two views into one is not possible because I need to process the date and generate the available time slots.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a lot of solution for it. You can do like this >>>
First of all
need to create 2 template form

one for contact details, reservation date, and number of guests,
second for booking available time slots.

```html
<!--form.html-->
<form action="{% url 'reservation_detail' %}">
Contact details: <input type="text" name="contact_detail">
reservation date: <input type="date" name="date">
number of guest: <input type="number" name="number_of_gueset">
<input type="submit" value="next">
</form>
```

```html
         #url.py
    path('booking_slot',view.booking_slot,name='booking_slot'),
    path('reservation_detail',view.reservation_detail,name='reservation_detail'),
    path('slot_book',view.slot_book,name='slot_book'),
    path('success',view.success,name='success'),
```

```html
#view.py

def booking_slot(request):
  render(request,'form.html')

def reservation_detail(request):
   if request.method='post':
      # get all data here
      slot_date = request.POST.get('date')
      # check here available time according to date 
      available_time = "all time"
      table = "available table array"
      data = {"contact_details":contact_details, "reservation_date":reservation_date, "number_of_guest":number_of_guest, "available_time":available_time,"table":table}
      render(request,'reservation_detail.html',data)
```

After that click on Next button, you will be redirected to reservation_data. render all data on this second view template (reservation_details.html) like this

```html
#reservation_detail.html

<form action="{% url 'slot_book' %}">
available time: <input type="date" name="available_time">

<!-- you can show here calender or time. it depends on you -->
Free table :    {% foreach availabletable_number in table %}
               table {{availabletable_number}} : <input type="checkbox" name="availabletime[]" value={{availabletable_number}}>
                {%endforeach%}
             
             <input tye="hidden" name="contact_details" value="{{contact_details}}">
             <input tye="hidden" name="reservation_date" value="{{reservation_date}}">
</form>
```

```html
#view.py

def slot_book(request):
    if request.method='post':
      # Get the form data from the post like this 
      slot_date = request.POST.get('date')
      
      #To save data, import your model or form here
      return redirect("/success")
      
def success(request):
    render(request,'success.html')
```

Please modify the code according to your requirement.
we can also use Ajax and By using a single form we can solve this problem.
If any questions let me know.